# Mask outer edges of data points in a 2d array

Tags: python, 2d, mask

I'm trying to create a mask around a 2d array of values that are not Nan. My goal is to mask points that are within 2 places of actual data. A quick example is outlined below, but this will be applied to a 2d array with size of 301,301.

```
array = ([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan,   8,   5, nan,   3, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan, nan,   2,   1, nan, nan, nan,   9, nan,],
          [nan, nan,   4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan,   8, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,   3, nan,],
          [nan, nan,   3, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan,   2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,   6, nan,],
          [nan, nan,   6, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,   4, nan,],
          [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,],
          [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,]])

mask = ([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

I could not find similar examples, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a `numpy` array or plain Python `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `arr` is a numpy array containing your values:

```
d = 2  # margin width around value cells to be set true in the mask
# indices of not-nan array cells
value_indices = np.argwhere(~np.isnan(arr))
# we initialize the mask with False
mask = np.zeros_like(arr).astype(bool)
# set the mask cells around indices with values (i.e. not nan) to True
for i, j in value_indices:
    mask[i-d:i+d+1, j-d:j+d+1] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might not be too elegant, but it will work. It assumes that all rows have the same length:

```
from itertools import product
from math import isnan

def mask(array, row, col):
    nan = float('nan')
    return any(not isnan(array[r][c]) for r, c in product(
        range(max(0, row-2), min(len(array)-1, row+3)), 
        range(max(0, col-2), min(len(array[0])-1, col+3))))

>>> masked = [[mask(array, r, c) for c in range(len(array[r]))] for r in range(len(array))]
[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```